# MVC AddJsonOptions ReferenceLoopHandling configuration not applied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 API C# project used by another ASP.NET Core 2 / Angular 2 application. I've configured the API project MVC service JSON option `ReferenceLoopHandling` to `Ignore` e.g.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

However, when I run my application I still get a "Self referencing loop detected...' error from one of my HTTP GET methods.

In debug mode, if I pause in the method before the result is serialized and manually run the serialization e.g.

```
?Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    myDataObject, 
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    })
```

the data is serialized without error as expected.

Why would the service configuration not be applied to this method?

Comment: This *should* work. You might need to share more code from your startup configuration and the action that is causing problems.

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET Core MVC has its own [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) object, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/MvcJsonOptions.cs#L17); It's what you configure when calling `AddJsonOptions`. Settings that you apply to this instance do not apply to the methods you might call off `JsonConvert`. In order to affect those methods, you need to set the [`DefaultSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm) property. e.g.:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
};
```

You can do this somewhere in your `Startup` class or perhaps even in your `Program` class.

Comment: OK, so my debug statement is not equivalent, I see. However, I still have the issue where the MVC service configuration is not applied when my API is accessed by a client i.e. the object model serialization fails at some point. I thought the MVC service AddJsonOptions configuration would apply to the API methods.

Comment: If this code snippet has *not* fixed your issue, then it's worth including more information in your question. The problematic action would be a good place to start.

Comment: I've since accessed the API via Postman and the data is serialized by the API as expected with the options applied so it must be the deserialization. I'll post back when I have more info.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take a look serpent5. I took out the includes from the repository and properties in my view model and reintroduced them to recreate the problem and now it works. I'm mystified.